# Numerical second order differentiation

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations

I have written a code for the second differentiation of numerical list

```
diff2list = {}; diff2 = ConstantArray[0, {Length@firstlist, 2}];
Do[

 diff2[[i]] = (firstlist[[i - 1, 2]] - 2 firstlist[[i, 2]] + firstlist[[i + 1, 2]])/(2*0.4);

  AppendTo[diff2list, {0.4*i, diff2[[i]]}]

    , {i, 2, Length@firstlist - 1}]
```

How can I change my code to be more efficient for larger lists and small intervals. The firstlist can be generated as below:

```
firstlist = Table[{0.4 i, N@Cos[\[Pi]/7 i]}, {i, 1, 30}];
```

However, my list is different from this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the two argument form of `Differences`  (`Differences[list, n]`) to get nth differences:

```
Transpose[{firstlist[[2 ;; -2, 1]], 
  Differences[firstlist[[All, 2]], 2] / 2 / {-1, 1}.firstlist[[{1, 2}, 1]]}]

% == diff2list
```

> True

Or make it a function:

```
ClearAll[diF2]
diF2 = Transpose[{Most@Rest@#, Differences[#2, 2]/2/(#[[2]] - #[[1]])} & @@ Transpose@#] &;

diF2 @ firstlist == diff2list
```

> True

You can also use the following alternatives to `Differences[lst, 2]`:

```
ListConvolve[{1., -2., 1.}, lst]
ListCorrelate[{1., -2., 1.}, lst]
{1, -2, 1}.{lst[[1 ;; -3]], lst[[2 ;; -2]], lst[[3 ;; -1]]}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you've been trained in a language other than *Mathematica* because your style and syntax take advantage of none of *Mathematica*'s unique power:

```
myList = RandomInteger[{0, 5}, 10];

diff2 = Differences[myList];

diff3 = Differences[diff2]
```

Comment: You are completely  right

Comment: Or `Nest[Differences, myList, 2]` if you want to do it all at once.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to take the differences often, it may pay off to assemble a `SparseArray` that does it for you:

```
n = 1000000;
A = Plus[
    DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray@ConstantArray[-2., n]],
    DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray@ConstantArray[1., n - 1], 1],
    DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray@ConstantArray[1., n - 1], -1]
    ][[2 ;; -2]];

myList = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
a = Differences[myList, 2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = Subtract[myList[[1 ;; -3]] + myList[[3 ;; -1]], 2. myList[[2 ;; -2]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
c = A.myList; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == b == c
```

> 0.0268
>
> 0.0064
>
> 0.0038
>
> True

I also suggest to keep the list of x- and y-values apart as two vectors of length $n$ (rather than muddling them to gether to a $n \times 2$ matrix); that will quicken the read operations that you will most likely perform on the data.